# Opening a file for output/input in Microsoft Visual Basic on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, visual-basic, office-for-mac, microsoft-excel-2011

I am working in Excel for Mac 2011 and my goal is to create a simple macro that writes particular cells to a file. This is generally a simple task, but VB chooses not to accept a file path. For example, the following code literally writes a file called `~/file.txt`, ignoring the directory structure entirely:

```
Open "~/file.txt" For Output As #1
```

I have tried the full path `/Users/Sergey/file.txt` to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

You have to retrace the path back to the hard disk. If I run

```
Open "testfile.txt" For Output As 1
```

the new file appears in `/Applications/Microsoft Office 2004/Templates/`

If I retrace back to the hard disk with

```
Open "..:..:..:Users:henrywhitney:Documents:Scribe:Macro Data:testfile.txt" For Output As 1
```

it appears in `/Users/henrywhitney/Documents/Scribe/Macro Data/`.

Comment: Henry - thank you so much - I had been struggling with this problem for hours, and it now works. You've made my day!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use `:` instead of `/`? Something like

```
":Users:Sergey:file.txt"
```

You can also try:

```
ThisWorkBook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "file.txt"
```

Comment: The former came up with an error: "Path not found." The latter worked out fine, however working relative to the excel document is not always the ideal scenario. For my purpose here, it did the job.

Comment: Thank you, this was my issue. Note: using `Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Path` helps a lot.